# Location of Virtual Pivot for a "four-bar linkage trapezoid"

Tags: geometry, kinematics

Greetings:  For the setup in the accompanying image, when Point N is displaced by "d" to N', How can I calculate the location of the Virtual Pivot Point (-X, 0)?  Thanks in advance for any assistance...

[four-bar linkage trapezoid with displacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKBvW.jpg)